# Adjunction induced by inclusion

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a cartesian closed category,  and suppose that $\mathbf{A}$ is a subcategory of $\mathbf{C}$ such that the inclusion $I$ is part of an adjunction $I\dashv F:\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{A}$, in which the unity is the identity. Assume that $\bf A$ is closed under the formation of binary products (for $x\in\mathbf{A}$ denote with $T:\mathbf{C}\to  \mathbf{C}$ the functor $-\times x$, and with $ T':\mathbf{A}\to  \mathbf{A}$ its restriction to $\bf A$). Is $\bf A$ cartesian closed?

We need to prove that $T'$ has a right adjoint; but if we prove $FTI=T'$,  the latter would have $F(-^x)I$ as a right adjoint. So we can notice that $$TI=IT'\implies FTI=FIT'=T'.$$
In fact if the unity  $1_\mathbf{A}\xrightarrow{\bf{.}} FI$ is the identity transformation, I'd  say that by definition the codomain $FI$ must be $1_\mathbf{A}$.

It seems quite strange that the solution is so simple, being in a written examination of the past years; do you  think I forgot something? Thanks

Comment: The right adjoint should be $F(-^x)I$, not $I(-^x)F$.

Comment: Is this from one of Sandra's old exams?

Comment: I corrected, thanks

Comment: @fosco yes it is!